# ColdFusion Problems with Both onError And cferror

Tags: javascript, html, server, coldfusion

I am having a problem wherein my onError method no longer works in my application.cfc file. The program was catching errors and displaying error.cfm correctly yesterday, but now I just get a 500 error. My manager may have changed a couple things in the file yesterday, but we seem to have recreated it and that fixed nothing.

I currently use onError, but I tried cferror. With cferror the data entry form won't even load.

The code is below. The onError is blocked because I am showing it with the cferror code. Just delete the cferror and blocks if you want to use it will onError:

```
<!--- this component controls the application's global settings / event 
handlers and maintains user sessions --->
<cfcomponent>

  <!--- define some basic settings --->

  <cfset this.name = "QualityDataPortal" />
  <cfset this.sessionManagement = "yes" />
  <cfset this.setClientCookies = "no" />
  <cfset this.loginStorage = "session" />
  <!--- this function is triggered when our application is initialized --->
  <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="no">
    <!--- define application variables --->
    <cfset application.dataSource = 'quality' />
    <!--- return out --->
    <cfreturn true />
  </cffunction>
  <cferror
    template="error.cfm"
    type="exception"
    mailTo="Generic@org.edu" />
  <!--- <!--- this function is triggered when coldfusion encounters an error --->
    <cffunction name="onError" access="public" returntype="void" output="no">
      <cfargument name="exception" required="yes">
      <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="yes">

      <!--- send a dump of the error via email --->
      <cfmail from="QDP@org.edu" to="Generic@org.edu" subject="Quality Data Portal Error Encountered" type="html">
        <cfoutput>
          The following error was encountered on #dateformat(now(), 'dddd mmmm dd, yyyy')# at #timeformat(now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt')#<br /><br />
          <cfdump var="#arguments.exception#">
          <cftry><cfdump var="#arguments#"><cfcatch></cfcatch></cftry>
          <cfdump var="#form#">
          <cfdump var="#session#">
          <cfdump var="#cgi#">
        </cfoutput>
      </cfmail>

      <!--- alert the user that an error has been encountered --->
      <cflocation url="error.cfm" addtoken="no">
      <cfabort />

    </cffunction> --->

  <!--- this function is triggered when coldfusion receives a request for a template it cannot locate --->
  <cffunction name="onMissingTemplate" access="public" returntype="void" output="no">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="yes">
    <!--- alert the user that the page they requested could not be found --->
    <cflocation url="404.cfm" addtoken="no">
    <cfabort />
    <!--- return out --->
    <cfreturn />
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: 500 errors are http, not coldfusion

Comment: I suspect your error handler code is throwing an error. Take out the `<cferror >` tag, you don't need it. Empty out your `onError` function to a minimum of sending the email.  Assuming that works, start adding code back in until it fails again.  Then fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, so you can see better, to remove unused code (cferror tag), remove unnecessary comments, don't nest comments.

Then, start with this code for `onError`

```
<cffunction name="onError" returntype="void" output="false">

    <cfargument name="exception" required="true">
    <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="true">

    <cfmail to="Generic@org.edu" from="QDP@org.edu" subject="Quality Data Portal Error Encountered" type="html">

        <cfoutput>The following error was encountered on #DateFormat(now(), "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")# at #TimeFormat(now(), "HH:nn:ss")#</cfoutput>
        <hr />
        <cfdump var="#exception#" label="Exception" />        
        <cfdump var="#form#" label="Form" /> 
        <cfdump var="#session#" label="Session" /> 
        <cfdump var="#cgi#" label="CGI" /> 

    </cfmail>

    <cflocation url="error.cfm" addtoken="false" />

</cffunction>
```

***Note:***

- Pay attention at this: `#timeformat(now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt')`, it should use `nn` for minutes not `mm`.
- There is no code after `<cflocation ...` since ColdFusion won't run it.

> Stops execution of the current page and opens a ColdFusion page or HTML file.
>   (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cac.html)

Comment: I would even suggest removing this line `<cflocation url="error.cfm" addtoken="false" />` initially. Assuming it works correctly the line can be added back to see if it still works or not. I suspect there is an issue with the code in that template. I don't think it is a good idea to cflocation to another page from an error handler anyway. Things get messy when that page also errors...

Comment: @Miguel-F, yes, I agree, there might be problems in there too it changes were made.